# iOS não respeita o overflow-x hidden

Tags: css, ios

Tenho um [site publicado](http://maurooficial.com/) e ele está apresentando uma rolagem lateral na versão *responsive* quando acessado via iPhone que não existe em mais nenhum dispositivo. Tanto no Safari quando no Chrome se acessado via iPhone. Dispositivos Android funcionam normalmente.

Eu já testei várias soluções como [essa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14270084/overflow-xhidden-doesnt-prevent-content-from-overflowing-in-mobile-browsers), não funcionam. Adicionei um container em volta de todo o conteúdo pra tentar dar `overflow-x: hidden` e não respeita. Tentei adicionar via javascript largura máxima = largura do dispositivo. Nada.

Removi parte por parte do código pra ver o que gera rolagem e basicamente é tudo que tá no centro mesmo, possivelmente tem a ver com os carrosséis. Também tentei dar `overflow-x: hidden` neles, `overflow: hidden`, tamanho fixo e etc. Nada funciona.

Não sei mais o que fazer. Alguém passou por isso?

Comment: Para fins de teste, tenta isso no seu CSS: `*{ overflow-x: hidden !important; }`.

Comment: Testou comentando ou retirando o carrossel para ver se o problema eh com ele mesmo?

Comment: Oi @Sam, sim. Já havia testado, não funciona.

Comment: @hugocsl sim, Hugo. Já fiz isso. O carrossel e o ScrollReveal tão gerando essa rolagem lateral.

Comment: Tentei dar uma olhada aqui, mas não tenho um ambiente de teste para visualizar essa barra horizontal, nessa não vou conseguir ajudar muito

Comment: @hugocsl Obrigada por tentar ajudar de qualquer forma :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Haviam 3 problemas relacionados ao overflow de conteúdo.

1. O primeiro estava relacionado a biblioteca [owlCarousel](https://owlcarousel2.github.io). Tive de adicionar largura fixa em pixels (estava usando percentual 100% do container) no *responsive*.
2. O segundo era relacionado ao [botão de subscribers do youtube](https://developers.google.com/youtube/youtube_subscribe_button?hl=pt-br) que estava incorporado no código. Tive de adicionar `overflow:hidden` no container de fora do botão.
3. O último relacionado a biblioteca [scrollReveal](https://scrollrevealjs.org/). Analisando [essa issue](https://github.com/scrollreveal/scrollreveal/issues/369) tentei resolver via CSS adicionando `overflow-x: hidden` para todos os elementos que estavam deslizando da esquerda ou da direita. Não funcionou. Então removi esse tipo de efeito em resoluções menores. Como ele estava sendo acionado por uma class, resolvi via *jQuery*

   `if($(window).width() < 680) {
       $('.rightShow').removeClass('rightShow');
       $('.leftShow').removeClass('leftShow');
    }`

Sei que se trata de problemas muito específicos e relacionados ao meu projeto, mas decidi publicar a resposta e manter o artigo para, eventualmente, dar uma "luz" para que tiver problemas parecidos. Possivelmente estarão relacionados a códigos incorporados.